# How to create custom quote template

Tags: apex, visualforce, html, quote, quote-template

I am curious how would you create a quote template through html, the inbuilt template don't appear to have this functionality.

Comment: It is possible to create, check it once https://www.sdocs.com/resources/documentation/creating-your-quotes-template/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this via visualforce, whilst it is finicky, you can create a visualforce action and utilize renderas to render a PDF.

This does take time, but you don't need to pay for a package,

Answer (score 0):

Visualforce cannot render HTML on CPQ quote templates. To get anything to show at all from a Rich Text field you will need to use HTMLENCODE() function in Visualforce and this will prevent rendering. Otherwise it will just output blank text. Use Conga or another Quote Template tool if you need to show HTML via Visualforce in CPQ Quote Templates.